# Vagrant boxes are connected?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

this is my vagrant box configuration setup:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  box_version = "0.0.1"

  config.vm.box = "Ubuntu precise 64 VirtualBox"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.20.4"
  config.vm.synced_folder "wordpress", "/var/www/", type: "nfs", mount_options: ['rw', 'vers=3', 'tcp', 'fsc']
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port",  guest: 80,   host: 9090

  config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  config.vm.provider(:virtualbox) do |vb|
    vb.customize [
      "modifyvm", :id,
      "--memory", "2048",
      "--cpus",   "4"
    ]
  end

end
```

There are two boxes with the exact same configuration, the only difference is the `host:` option. the one here states 9090, the other one states 8080.

The issue is, I start one, the other is started. I halt one the other halts as well. I do not get an error stating the port is in use in fact they both start up and both shut down when one is started and or stopped.

I originally set up the 8080 one to do WordPress development. I needed the same box for a different WP project so I just copied the folder and in the copied folder deleted the .vagrant folder and re-ran vagrant up thinking they would be separate boxes.

Nope, same issue when one starts the other starts, when one shuts down the other does too. They are the same box.

What do I have to change so they are different boxes, but use the same OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a separate name defined for each different Vagrantfile, VirtualBox is probably treating them as the same virtual machine.

To fix that, you can alter each Vagrantfile by setting the `vb.name` parameter separately, like this:

```
config.vm.provider(:virtualbox) do |vb|
  vb.customize [
    "modifyvm", :id,
    "--memory", "2048",
    "--cpus",   "4"
  ]
  vb.name = "box1"
end
```

Name them "box1", "box2", or with whatever convention you want. Then as long as the Vagrant files are in separate directories, you'll have independent VMs.